Why are my icons becoming blurry in Unity?
For some reason, I'm getting very bad quality in my game and edit scene in Unity. Take a look at two menu buttons that are about the same size. They both come out in different resolutions. This occurs when I build the game too. I also seem to have issues with text at low fonts. Looking at other games and just a Word document, I would think I could get down to this size before the resolution becomes a problem.
I've checked as many settings as I can to make sure everything aligns. See the Canvas settings in the second image and the GameObect/Button settings in the third image.
Does anyone know any tricks to getting images to show at a fine resolution?
This is the discrepancy:


These are my Canvas settings:

These are the settings for the GameObject:

These are the Sprite settings:


If you can't make sprite pixel perfect or integer multiple scaling, you have to bear this result.

@shingo how do you make it pixel perfect or integer multiple scaling?

Adjust it out. The image is 96x96, then it is better to display it in this size on the screen. And make sure you view the actual size, Unity‘s scene window is usually scaled.

Ideas: Improve compression quality (on symbols like these, I personally apply no compression) and activate mipmap generation. The "filter mode" is also crucial as it's the algorithm that's being applied when scaling.

Check out the 2D Pixel Perfect package.

If its meant to be low resolution or pixilated in your case 96x96, try changing on the sprite in the inspector the filter mode to "point" and the compression to "none". Hope that helps
